# Using value of abstract method called at runtime

Tags: java, android, abstract-class, android-location, abstract-methods

I'm trying to use MyLocation class from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-in-a?answertab=active#tab-top). In code below I need to access variable currentLat and currentLon anywhere inside the class instantiating MyLocation. I don't know how to access value of `currentLat` and `currentLon`

`LocationResult locationResult = new LocationResult(){
     @Override
     public void gotLocation(Location location){
        currentLat = location.getLatitude();
        currentLon = location.getLongitude();
    }; 
}
        MyLocation myLocation = new MyLocation();
        myLocation.getLocation(this, locationResult);`

Suppose I want here

`Double x =currentLoc;`

how to I get that? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of anonymous class use your own that extends/implments LocationResult class/interface and add getter like this

```
    class MyLocationResult extends/implments LocationResult{
    double currentLat;
    double currentLon;

    @Override 
    public void gotLocation(Location location){ 
        currentLat = location.getLatitude(); 
        currentLon = location.getLongitude(); 
    };
    public double getCurrentLat(){
       return currentLat;
    }
    public double getCurrentLon (){
       return currentLon ;
    }
}
```

then you can write

```
MyLocationResult locationResult = new MyLocationResult();
MyLocation myLocation = new MyLocation(); 
myLocation.getLocation(this, locationResult);
```

and whenever you need currentLat or currentLon you can write

```
locationResult.getCurrentLat();
```

Comment: It's returning 0.0 
I tried setter too but no help. Inside gotLocation method of MYLocationResult value displayed but outside that everywhere it's 0.0

Comment: well you can call getCurrentLat only when gotLocation() was called before , so if you require getCurrentLat but it is not set yet you will have 0.0

Answer (score 0):

You can use `static` modifiers for your variables and define them globally..

```
public static double currentLat; // defined globally...
public static double currentLon;

LocationResult locationResult = new LocationResult(){
   @Override
      public void  gotLocation(Location location){
      currentLat =location.getLatitude(); // assuming getLatitude() returns double or int
      currentLon = location.getLongitude();
    };
}
MyLocation myLocation = new MyLocation();
myLocation.getLocation(this, locationResult);
```

Now you can access them anywhere

```
double x =currentLon;
double y =currentLat;
```

Comment: I'm getting 0.0 but inside LocationResult value is not 0

Comment: Are you sure the value is not `0.0` ? Trying Logging the values right after this line `currentLat =location.getLatitude();`
put this line and then try !
`Log.e("method1 returns",""+location.getLatitude());`